# How does pressure cooker increase cooking speed?

Tags: thermodynamics

My teacher mentioned something about pressure cookers making cooking faster and I was wondering what exactly is the reason behind this?

Comment: Because the temperature inside is higher, and higher temperatures speed up the chemical reactions that make up cooking...

Comment: Higher pressure means that the temperature can get higher for a given volume.

Answer (score 0):

If we heat a liquid, the average Kinetic Energy of the liquid increases and at a certain stage, the energy becomes sufficient to break the molecular attraction. The molecules anywhere in the liquid can form vapor bubbles. These bubbles float to the surface of the liquid and finally come out of the liquid. This phenomena is called boiling and temperature at which it occurs is called boiling point. The boiling point of a liquid depends on the external pressure over its surface. When pressure **decreases**, boiling point **decreases**. That's why at place with high altitude, water will boil before reaching 100 degree Celsius. For example, boiling point of water at 1atm is 100 degree Celsius but at 0.5atm it is 82 degree Celsius. 
*A pressure cooker is a sealed pot with a valve that controls the steam pressure inside. As the pot heats up, the liquid inside forms steam, which raises the pressure in the pot.*This enables us to cook at a higher temperature, making the process faster.